# Bug in snippet's "Tidy" button

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-snippets, tidy

If you have a snippet in a StackOverflow post and you hit the Tidy button, the result is not always equivalent to the original!

Take this snippet for instance

```html
<input name = textbox>
```

Then if you hit Tidy, the result is as follows.

```html
<input name=t extbox>
```

That is, whenever an attribute value is unquoted and is preceded by one or more spaces, tidy inserts a space after the first letter of the value.

(Note that while unquoted attribute values are not recommended, they're perfectly valid HTML, as is using spaces around the `=` sign.)

Can this be corrected?

Comment: Of course, this argues for always quoting your attributes in HTML... :). Still a bug though.

Comment: Only happens when there is a space after the `=` and the attribute value isn't quoted. e.g. `<input name= textbox>`

Comment: Actually, the expected result is wrong. It should tidy the code to `<input name="" textbox>`. Any value with a space, after the `=`, is an attribute (when unquoted). The tidy function is trying too hard to remove `textbox` from being an attribute to being a value, when it should give it just a pair of quotes (to indicate an empty attribute). Consider this:  `<input type=checkbox checked= disabled>`. What do you expect? I expect `checked` to have an empty string, as it should be parsed. That example should produce `<input type="checkbox" checked="" disabled>`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Your assumption about spaces is wrong. spaces around = signs are valid in HTML! `attr=value` means exactly the same as `attr= value`. See the [official parsing rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/parsing.html#concept-get-attributes-when-sniffing).

Comment: @MrLister Spaces are attribute separators.

Comment: @MrLister I can't make sense out of that link

Comment: The link says 1) skip preceding spaces (and tabs etc), 2..5) read the attribute name, 6) skip spaces 7..8) read the =, 9) skip spaces, 10..12) read the value.

Comment: @MrLister: The rules on the page you linked to are specifically about the pre-parsing step of determining the character encoding (which can require a preliminary parsing step to sniff for `<meta>` tags, hence the inclusion of those pseudo-parsing rules there). That said, [the actual HTML attribute syntax](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#attributes-2) does also clearly permit whitespace around the `=` sign.

Comment: `<input name = textbox>` may be valid but I am consumed by physical revulsion when I look at it.  Maybe the **Tidy** engine feels the same?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, declined.

While it may be strictly "legal", using unquoted attributes is widely recognized as a bad practice, and can lead to [nothing but problems](https://css-tricks.com/problems-with-unquoted-attributes/). Code snippets (and all code blocks, for that matter) in Stack Overflow are used, amongst other things, as a learning resource by beginner developers; therefore it would be a good idea to try and post proper code whenever possible.

So considering that, while strictly speaking this is indeed a bug, we are not going to invest time in fixing it. Consider that bug kind of a "punishment" for not following best practices. :-)

Comment: [The other bug you reported](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309573/another-bug-in-snippets-tidy-button), however, "seems legit". I'm taking a look at it.