# Another bug in snippet's “Tidy” button

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, tidy

I found another bug with the Tidy button in the stack snippets.

(By the way, [my earlier bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306941/bug-in-snippets-tidy-button) still hasn't been resolved.)

This one is about the CSS.

If one of the parts of a selector starts with a colon, the "Tidy" button removes the whitespace before it.
Example:

```css
tr :first-child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>h1</th><th>h2</th><th>h3</th></tr>
  <tr><td>a1</td><td>a2</td><td>a3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>b1</td><td>b2</td><td>b3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Hitting Tidy will change the css selector to `tr:first-child`, which is not the same! In this case, it selects the table's first row instead of the first column.

Steps to reproduce: Copy snippet to answer, edit the above snippet, click "Run", see the result. Now click "Tidy" and then "Run" again. See the difference!

So, can this be corrected?

Edit:
To address the comments to the (deleted) answer: yes, these are different selectors! `xx:yy` means pseudo-class `yy` on element `xx`, while `xx :yy` with a space means pseudo-class `yy` on any *child element* of element `xx`. This is the official definition, and it doesn't need `*` to be correct, validating CSS.
Also, yes, `*` can be used to work around the bug, but it's still a bug.

Comment: @canon can we close this as typo? :P

Comment: Indeed this looks like a bug. Taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No point in arguing here: `foo :bar` is not the same as `foo:bar` (and the same for `::`), it only takes a small test on any web sandbox to verify it. Fixed, thank you.

Comment: What's with the select/option formatting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005122/send-email-using-javascript-html-and-ajax